# How could I display different ViewController from ViewController attached to UITabBarControLler

Tags: ios

using Interface Builder and Storyboared, I built UITabBarController with 3 views. By default, when user open application, first View displayed, but under certain criteria, I need 2nd view to get displayed.

Hence, from AppDelgate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, i need to display -present - the 2nd view controller;

notice, I tried to do something like this:

```
[myfirstcontrooler presentViewController:mycontrooler animated:YES completion: nil];
```

but I got

> Application tried to present modally an active controller

error & crash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mycontrooler animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks ... I don't have navigationController property in my Appdelgate? how could I get navigationController ?

Comment: Ah sorry, I only read the caption and the code. Well then just try the code, but instead of using self.navigationcontroller use myfirstcontrooler?

Comment: the error disappeared now, but nothing happened. fist view is still showing, I think I mistake in referencing 1st and 2nd views. do you have a more full example?

Comment: I tried also this, but nothing happened: [[self.window rootViewController].navigationController pushViewController:my2ndcontroller animated:YES ];

Comment: Mmh you say you are putting the code in the appdelegte didfinsihlaunching because you wanna show 2nd controller under certain circumstances? Why don't put the code in the 1st view controller, hence this is anyway the first one that is going to pop up? Put it in the viewDidload and try it with an if statement. If the criteria is met than switch to second viewcontroller and use the above code, but instead of self.navcon, user myfirstcontrooler